# PersistenceException while trying to cascade persist child entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I have 2 entities:

**Master:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "master")
public class Master implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "seq")
    private Integer seq;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "seq", referencedColumnName = "seq")
    private SubMaster subMaster;


    ...................

}
```

**Sub Master:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sub_master")
public class SubMaster implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "seq")
    private Integer seq;

    private String subName;


    ...................

}
```

When, I am trying to persist `Master` entity by setting the `SubMaster` entity, I am getting following exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned beforeQuery calling save(): SubMaster
```

Whereas, I am expecting that Hibernate it will automatically persist child entity whenever parent entity is persisted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you inverted the owner of the association as i believe subMaster should have the @JoinColumn annotation.

now for the solution

Depends on JPA version:

-2.0 you can define `@Id` annotation on relation annotation so you could have something like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "master")
public class Master implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "seq")
    private Integer seq;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "master", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private SubMaster subMaster;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "sub_master")
public class SubMaster implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "seq", referencedColumnName = "seq")
    @OneToOne
    private Master master;

    private String subName;

}
```

where you tell your child entity to take the id of the parent

```
master.setSubMaster(subMaster);
subMaster.setMaster(master)
```

-1.0 you are pretty much stuck as you are forced to place `@Id` on a basic annotation so you need to have an id and a relation column separated, the problem is that with `@GeneratedValue` you are forced to first save the parent and then manually set the id to the child before saving

ref: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Primary_Keys_through_OneToOne_and_ManyToOne_Relationships

Answer (score 2):

add @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY) for SubMaster as well, seems like it's SubMaster's id that generated the exception

Comment: but, I believe for SubMaster id should be same as Master's. However, if i use this, I am getting exception (which i think is obvious): `java.sql.SQLException: Field 'seq' doesn't have a default value`

Comment: What would be the point of having the same id for both ? OneToOne will generate a foreign key reference. If you want to join with Master id too, you need to specify a second column to join, and add an id_master attribute in your sub_master class.
Besides, you may disable null entry for seq element because of the join (it could be the source of the exception)